# ssh remote run of a local file using paramiko in Python

Tags: ssh

I am new to Python coding. I have a piece of shell code as below. I am attempting to convert this to Python.

```
cat <file> |ssh -q  ${v_user}@${v_server} > /tmp/.bndchk.log
```

Using this through shell script, I am running a local file that has required commands over remote server through ssh.

Now, I am looking for the similar action in python as well.

Could you help me on this, please?

Thank you so much in advance.

With best wishes,
Macharla Ramesh Kumar